# Toggle play/pause button (Multiple audios)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple audios on my page, each with play/pause button.

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php

        // the query
        $predigten_all_query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'=>'predigten',
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

        <?php if ( $predigten_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="content-box">
            <!-- the loop -->
            <?php while ( $predigten_all_query->have_posts() ) : $predigten_all_query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php
                // vars
                $mp3 = get_field('mp3');
                $mp3_url = $mp3['url'];
            ?>
            <div class="archive-content">
                <div class="play-wrap">
                    <audio src="<?php echo $mp3_url; ?>" id="music"></audio>
                    <i class="fa fa-play" id="play"></i>
                </div>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3><br>
                <a href="<?php echo $mp3_url; ?>" class="mp3-btn" download>
                    <i class="fa fa-share-square-o"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- end of the loop -->
        </div>
```

Here is my script that changes class of icon so it can toggle to "play" or "pause" icon.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#play").click(function() {
        var audio = document.getElementById('music');
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            $('#play').removeClass('fa fa-play')
            $('#play').addClass('fa fa-pause')
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0
            $('#play').removeClass('fa fa-pause')
            $('#play').addClass('fa fa-play')
        }
    });
});
```

Problem is that this works only for my first audio button. Do I need to create a dynamic IDs and if I need to do it, how to do everything right??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have multiple `#play` and `#music` elements in the DOM when they must be unique. You can solve the issue by using a class on the play button instead, then using DOM traversal in the click handler to find the related `audio` element. Try this:

```
<div class="play-wrap">
  <audio src="<?php echo $mp3_url; ?>" class="music"></audio>
  <i class="fa fa-play play"></i>
</div>
```

```js
$(".play").click(function() {
  var audio = $(this).closest('.play-wrap').find('.music')[0];

  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0
  }

  $(this).toggleClass('fa-play fa-pause');
});
```

Also note the use of `toggleClass()` to simplify the changing of the classes between play states.

Comment: Hi how can we else if next audio is played current audio will pause

Comment: Hi how can we be able to get the length of var audio? audio.length is undefined

Answer (score 0):

html changes 
you can use the data attr for this.
set dynamically id to aution id and that id also set to in data-music_id

```
<div class="play-wrap">
<audio src="<?php echo $mp3_url; ?>" id="music1"></audio>
<i class="fa fa-play" id="play" data-music_id="music1"></i>
</div>
```

js changes

get the data-music_id and pass in to document.getElementById

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#play").click(function() {
var music_id = $(this).data('music_id');
    var audio = document.getElementById(music_id);
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        $('#play').removeClass('fa fa-play')
        $('#play').addClass('fa fa-pause')
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        audio.currentTime = 0
        $('#play').removeClass('fa fa-pause')
        $('#play').addClass('fa fa-play')
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Please describe the problem and the changes you've made. Dumping code doesn't educate anyone. You're also creating the same duplicate id issue with the `#music` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `class="play"` instead of `id="play"` if you have multiple play and audio.

on `play` click find `closest` audio and play or pause that audio.

```
<div class="play-wrap">
<audio src="<?php echo $mp3_url; ?>" class="music"></audio>
<i class="fa fa-play" class="play"></i>
</div>
<div class="play-wrap">
<audio src="<?php echo $mp3_url; ?>" class="music"></audio>
<i class="fa fa-play" class="play"></i>
</div>
```

Js changes

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".play").click(function() {
        var audio = $(this).closest('.audio');
        if (audio.paused) {
            audio.play();
            $(this).removeClass('fa fa-play')
            $(this).addClass('fa fa-pause')
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0
            $(this).removeClass('fa fa-pause')
            $(this).addClass('fa fa-play')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please describe the problem and the changes you've made. Dumping code doesn't educate anyone. Also note that jQuery objects do not have a `paused` property or `play()` or `pause()` methods.